Skeptical about firmware updates on 2014 Fiat 500L
I would like insight about firmware updates on my car to know if they are really necessary.
I brought my 2014 Fiat 500L to the garage yesterday for a checkup and maintenance. Among the maintenances operations to plan, the garage wrote the following: "flash IPC/BCM module".
I called the garage and asked what it is. They said it is two updates, that I have to do, one for the dashboard electronics and one for the engine electronics. I respectfully asked for details: "what do these updates do?" The garage employee answered that he was in a hurry, and he said something like "updates are important. We do them all year long. They give us more precision when we fix engines, because they give us more details about faulty components and if you don't do them, it can easily cost you 200-300€."
I was surprised and looked up my IPC updates for my car. This website came up about a 2023 update.This is what the page says:

The oil pressure indicator may be flashing when the “Change Engine Oil” message is displayed.
A new software update for the instrument panel cluster (IPC) is now available. Once the software update is complete, only the “change engine oil” message will be displayed when prompted by the ECU and the oil pressure indicator will not flash at the same time.

I could not find information about BCM updates.
The garage told me they charge one hour of worktime for one update, and I have two (so around 150-160€ total).
I am not really willing to pay for an update that will just change the behavior of one LED. But if updates are more important for the car to operate correctly, of course I will do them.

Are firmware updates really crucial?
Can I do them myself with an OBD adapter?


Are you sure they said BCM? I only ask because there is a service bulletin that relates to the PCM (Powertrain Control Module) which would fit better with them mentioning the other one as being "engine electronics", the BCM would be the "Body Control Module" which is more ancillaries like keys, windows and lights etc

I think it's unlikely that your garage tech actually look at the details of what each update does. They likely just see that there's an update available, and want to install it because it might make some troubleshooting easier for them.

Are they a main dealer? In my view, a main dealer will offer every item of work that they can, on the basis that they have an endless stream of wealthy customers who know nothing. One experience was the dealer offered to fit an upgraded version of one of the radiator fans, on the grounds that I would have "peace of mind", their favourite expression. You can't fault them for saying that updates are available, but saying that two will take twice as long as one, is like saying that delivering two pizzas will cost double, as if the updating machine needs to be put away and reconnected.
